# Using a template in multiple data-bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery-templates, knockout.js

I'm having trouble using a template bound multiple times.

For instance this is fine:

```html
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'searchField-template', 
                           foreach: Title, 
                           templateOptions: { checkedField: 'TitleSelected' } }">
</ul>
```

However, if I add the following:

```html
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'searchField-template', 
                           foreach: Manager, 
                           templateOptions: { checkedField: 'ManagerSelected' } }">
</ul>
```

Then I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_destroy' of undefined" at line 1894

Am I doing something wrong? Is there an alternate way, or is this a bug in knockout.js?

I'm using version 1.2.1.

Comment: Are you sure `Manager` is not undefined? It seems the value being passed to the template is not set. Either `Manager` or `ManagerSelected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout does not have a problem using a template multiple times or even using a template recursively.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/aqBQs/

There is likely something else going on in your scenario.  If you can reproduce it based on that sample, then I would be happy to help troubleshoot.

Comment: how embarrassing. Problem was elsewhere